# Davies-Bouldin Index higher or lower score better

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

[image: Here]

I trained a KMEANS clustering model using Google Bigquery, and it gives me these metrics in the evaluation tab of my model. My question is are we trying to maximize or minimize Davies-Bouldin index and mean-squared distance?

Comment: Read up about this metrics, and choose some simpler metrics like co variance instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Davies-Bouldin index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davies%E2%80%93Bouldin_index) is a validation metric that is often used in order to evaluate the optimal number of clusters to use. It is defined as a ratio between the cluster scatter and the cluster’s separation and a lower value will mean that the clustering is better.

Regarding the second metric, the mean squared distance makes reference to the intra cluster variance, which we want to minimize as a lower WCSS (within-cluster sums of squares) will [maximize the distance between clusters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158210/k-means-why-minimizing-wcss-is-maximizing-distance-between-clusters).

---